# Javascript how to show each element of array on a new line

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have a string build form comma separated values I use `split` to get each value and after that I want to show each value on a new line but what really happens is that I get each value on a new line except of the last two which are shown together on a same line. Just to make it clear:

> value1
>
> ,value2
>
> ,value3
>
> ,value4,value5

Here is the function which I'm using:

```
_checkDates: function(dates) {
    if (dates != null)
    {
        var zzz = dates.split(',');
        var xxx = zzz.length;
        console.log(xxx);
        for (var i=0; i<=xxx; i++)
        {
            zzz[i] = zzz[i] + '<br />';
            return zzz;
        }
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Just to be clear this is written in ExtJS 4, I'm almost sure that in this case the problem is pure JavaScript and is not related with ExtJS 4 but anyways, maybe I'm wrong.

So any ideas why does it happen and how I could make that last element to get on a new line as well?

Comment: why in your for loop do have an equal sign. it should be less then. eg. if zzz has length 5 (xxx=5) you want to access elements 0 to 4, value 1 index =0, value2 index =1, value3 index =2, value4 index =3 and value5 index=4. currently you are doing 0 to 5. because the loop exits after you reach 5 not 4. thus you are trying to access zzz[5] which doesn't have any value.

Comment: I know that, but i tried with `<` and `<=` even with `==` it didn't work. I don't know the reason why the `<br />` tag is not assigned, in fact that is why I post the question. The answer of Stefan below solve my current problem but I would be grateful if someone tell me where is the mistake in my script and how to modify it in order to work properly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The for-loop is suspicious. Firstly, you do not process all items (the last one is missing, as @sarfraz pointed out). Sencondly you are returning the result (`zzz`) in the for-loop body:

```
for (var i=0; i<=xxx; i++)
{
  zzz[i] = zzz[i] + '<br />';
  return zzz; // for-loop will stop here! resulting in ["value1<br />", "Value2", etc...]
}
```

In Javscript you can simple "join" the array:

```
return dates.split(',').join("<br />")
```

Since you are simply replacing strings you could use the `replace` method:

```
return dates.replace(",", "<br />");
```

Comment: `return dates.split(',').join("<br />")` - exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 46):

i have modified your function bit cleaner.since already stefan mentioned your mistake.

```
function splitDate(dates) {
    if (dates != null)
    {
        var dates = dates.split(',');
        var xxx = dates.length;
        console.log(xxx);
        for (var i=0; i<xxx; i++)
        {
            dates[i] = dates[i];                    
        }
    }
    console.log(dates.join('\r\n'));
    return dates.join('\r\n');        
}
```

the above function you can do it in a single line:

**if it's an array you can split into new line in following way:**

```
var arr = ['apple','banana','mango'];
console.log(arr.join('\r\n'));
```

**if it's a string:**

```
var str = "apple,banana,mango";
console.log(str.split(',').join("\r\n"));
```

Comment: you can do `console.log(arr.join('<br>'));`

Comment: `arrayVar.forEach(_ => console.log(_))` in case you can try this too in looping

Answer (score 3):

Link: https://snack.expo.io/GcMeWpPUX

```
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',margin:20 }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={your_array_name}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                        return (
                            <Text style={{ color: '#ff8500', fontSize: 18 }}>{item.skills.splice(',').join("\n")}</Text>
                        )
                    }}
                />

            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }

}


const your_array_name = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Lorem ipsum is simple dummy text for printing the line',
        skills: ['javascript', 'java']
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Lorem ipsum is simple dummy text.',
        skills: ['javascript', 'java']
    }]
```

Comment: thanks @Hardik Desai your solution helped me to fix the issue while rendering the array

Comment: @vaibhavnaik Welcome ✌️ ;)

Comment: Thank you, that was a great help.
.splice(',').join("\n"), worked in a simple way for me.